# Почему система убивает процесс запущенный сервисом?

Tags: android, activity, android-service, activity-life-cycle

Когда приложение сворачиваю или выключаю экран, то время останавливается.
Почему? Пробовал три варианта.

1. `Activity` создает `handler` и передает его в сервис. Сервис запускает `Timer`. `Timer` раз в секунду отправляет через `handler` свое состояние (обновляет `TextView` в исходном `Activity`). Т.е. просто "тикает" время в углу экрана.
2. Все то же самое, только использую не класс `Timer`, а просто создаю `Thread`. И `Service` его запускает. Этот `Thread` через `handler` обновляет элемент `Activity`.
3. Не создаю никаких потоков, вся логика в основном потоке `Service` - виснет `UI`.

Почему так и как сделать так, чтоб работало?

Comment: покажи код, чтоб тебе могли помочь